# Overriding functions that takes inherited structures

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

```
struct struct1
{};
struct struct2:public struct1
{};
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo(struct1 *s)
    {
        cout<<"foo in Base"<<endl;
    }
};
class Der:public Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo(struct2 *s)
    {
        cout<<"Foo in Der"<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    struct2 s;
    Base *b = new Der();
    b->foo(&s);
}
```

When I call the function in main It calls the member in Base."foo in Base" gets printed. It prints "foo in Der" when the Derived class function takes struct1 pointer. But Is there any way to make it take struct2 pointer and display "foo in Der"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for, interpreting that you mean to *override* the behavior of `Base::foo`, would be co-variant arguments to the function, and that is not possible in OO, as the derived type would be narrowing the contract of the base type, and thus it would break the Liskov Substitution Principle. You would not be able to substitute an object of type `Base` with an object of type `Der`, as the latter does not accept a `struct1` object that is not a `struct2` object.

When the derived type function has the same *signature* (i.e. also takes a `struct1*`), then it *overrides* the behavior of the `Base` and dynamic dispatch kicks in. But when you the signature has `struct2*` it does not *override* but rather *hides* the `Base` function.

Comment: Is the Liskov Substitution Principle failing because the member function foo in Der uses struct2 pointer which can't accept a struct1 pointer?

Comment: @sajas: Yes, the LSP requires that you should be able to replace any use of the base with the derived type. In this case that cannot be done, as there are uses of the base (in particular calling `foo` with a `struct1` object that is not `struct2`) that won't work for the derived type, and because of this, you cannot substitute the derived type in place of the base.